# Program flow stops when asking the user for input in a calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to code an algorithm that needs to add or subtract a certain number of value that the user gives. The sum or difference between this numbers is decided by the user writing on console the word "Addition" or "Subtract".

The problem is that the normal flow of the algorithm is stopped right when I let the user decide the operation he needs.

```
print("Hello User, know that I am an addition and subtraction calculator. You will have to choose which operation to perform!")
numbers = int(input("First choose how many numbers you have to add:"))
counter = 0
if numbers>0:
    print("Well, I see you only have " + str(numbers) + " numbers! Choose which operation you want to do!")
    x = "Addition", "addition"
    y = "Subtraction", "subtraction"
    print("Addition or maybe a subtraction?")
    choose_user = str(input())
    if choose_user == str(x):
        print("Okay perfect! Insert your numbers: ")
        while counter != numbers:
            counter = counter + 1
            number_user = int(input("Number to add:"))
            somma = 0
            somma = somma + int(number_user)
        print("Your answer is: " + somma)
    elif str(choose_user) == str(y):
        print("Okay perfect! Insert your numbers: ")
        while counter != numbers:
            counter = counter + 1
            number_user = int(input("Number to subtract:"))
            differenza = number_user
            differenza = differenza - number_user
        print("Your answer is: " + differenza)
```

Comment: If you `print(str(x))` you will probably see what the problem is here. You could more cleanly do something like `if choose_user.lower() == 'addition':`

Comment: `if choose_user == str(x)` This will never be true.  Use `if choose_user in x` instead.